# Paginator Not Found when page number specified

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I manually set the CakePHP Pagination values in my Usergals Controller like so, so as to Paginate a related Model (TreasuresUsergal) on the view of Usergal. Here is a simplified snippet from the UsergalController:

```
public function view($id = null) {

$this->loadModel('TreasuresUsergal');
    $options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'treasures',
    'alias' => 'Treasure2',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Treasure2.id = TreasuresUsergal.treasure_id',
        )
        )
    );

    $options['conditions']=array('TreasuresUsergal.usergal_id'=>$id);
    $options['fields']=array('Treasure2.*','TreasuresUsergal.ord','TreasuresUsergal.comments');
    $options['order']=array('TreasuresUsergal.ord'=>'asc');
    $options['limit']=$limit;
    $this->Paginator->settings = $options;
    $treasures=$this->Paginator->paginate('TreasuresUsergal');
    $this->set('treasures',$treasures);

}
```

So in the above example, $id is the value passed to the view function from the URL. There is a live example of this here:

http://collections.centerofthewest.org/usergals/view/20

As you can see, it works just fine for a single page. However, today I tested the Paginator in the view and discovered the "next" button does not work. The Counter, sorting, and Page numbers all load correctly - but anytime the actual named parameter "page:n" is passed (when n is greater than 1) I get a Not Found page with the following error:

```
Not Found

Error: The requested address '/usergals/view/20/page:2?url=%2Fusergals%2Fview%2F20' was not found on this server.
```

I must be missing something simple - I have experimented with the routes a little, but haven't been able to figure it out. Or perhaps I am missing some Paginator options? Or does it think its OutOfBounds when its not?

**UPDATE / WORKAROUND**

After some messing around, I have devised this workaround. Not as nice as I'd like, but here is the basic idea (error handling, etc can be added)

First, I added a check in beforeFilter to see if page paramter was set. If so, I change it to 'p' parameter and redirect.

I did this here because otherwise I had problems with the Not Found exception (see notes at bottom). So, in beforeFilter:

```
if (isset($this->params['named']['page'])){
    $newurl=$this->params['named'];
    $pg=$newurl['page'];
    unset($newurl['page']);
    $newurl['p']=$pg;
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view/'.$this->params['pass'][0])+$newurl);
}
```

Then, in the 'view' function of the same controller, I added this along with the other Paginator options:

```
if (isset($this->params['named']['p'])) $options['page']=$this->params['named']['p'];
```

With this, the standard Paginator behavior seems to work fine in the view. Prev, next, etc.

If anyone has a better suggestion, I would love to hear it. I don't like the idea of having to redirect, but it works for now.

It's worth noting that adding this code (even just to experiment) - caused all of my pagination counts to stop working. The query in debug was correct, but the displayed counts were wrong:

```
try {
        $this->Paginator->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {

        }
```

Comment: Where is this $limit coming from? Also I am not sure if this is a good way: 'Treasure2.*' have you tried to write each Treasure2. statement for all fields, I know it will  be time consuming but just to make sure if that (*) char is not messing arround your query.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I should've mentioned that I hard-coded $limit to 100 - I just plan on having it be a variable someday so I did it that way. See my update for the workaround I've been plotting.